# Extract dataframe value based on SQL query

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

I'm looking to store data into a dataframe field based on an sql query. Here's my attempt:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as ps
from datetime import datetime
from pandasql import sqldf

conx_string = "driver={SQL SERVER}; server=mssql_db; database=db; UID=usr; PWD=my_pwd;"
conn = pyodbc.connect(conx_string)
crsr = conn.cursor()
query = "select OrderID, OrderDate, OrigOrderID, from tbl_Orders"
'''
Example of return for my sql statement:
OrderID  | OrderDate  | OrigOrderID
-----------------------------------
23       | 15-02-2023 | NULL
24       | 16-02-2023 | 23
'''
data = crsr.execute(query)
rows = [list(x) for x in data]
columns = [column[0] for column in crsr.description]
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)

for i,row in df.iterrows():
    df.at[i, 'Date of receipt of OrigOrder'] = ps.sqldf(f"select OrderDate from tbl_Orders where OrderID='{df.at[i, 'OrigOrderID']}'")
    print(df.at[i, 'Date of receipt of OrigOrder'])
'''
Example of 'Date of receipt of OrigOrder' for 'OrderID = 24'
--> print(df.at[i, 'Date of receipt of OrigOrder']) should return '15-02-2023' as it is the date of its 'OrigOrderID = 23'
```

I'm expecting to have a new column `df['Date of receipt of OrigOrder']` (object) having `df['OrderDate']` of `df['OrigOrderID']` per row.

Any help please?

Comment: I think it would help if you have the results of your SQL query and what you would like it to look like as a final result in code format.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why not use `pandas.read_sql`/`pandas.read_sql_query`?

Comment: @Timus because pandas only support SQLAlchemy connectable(engine/connection) ordatabase string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connectionother DBAPI2 objects are not tested. I'm using MS SQL.